# wxLua remotely accessible GUI

Tags: user-interface, lua, wxwidgets, wxlua

I wanted to make a simple GUI for my application that would run on a linux based system and I want to make GUI that could be accessed remotely. I wanted to know if such a thing was possible with wxlua. That is, can I make a wxLua GUI for an application on a linux kernel and access that GUI from a remote system? If yes, how can I do that? I have written my preliminary wxLua program and it is working locally. Now I only need to make it accessible remotely.
I am pretty inclined towards wxLua as I find it easy and attractive. You can refer to [Norman Ramsey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2136964/2426016) here to know more.
But if there's a better method, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have a choice between running the entire GUI remotely and then using some kind of remote desktop protocol (if the server is on Linux, the typical choice would be [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing)) or running a non-GUI server part remotely and connecting to it from a local GUI.

The former is trivial but doesn't give optimal results from the point of view of user-friendliness. The latter does, but is more complicated to realize and at the very least requires separating your application in the client and server parts.